# Need MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE create an MP4 video

Tags: java, android, video, capture, mediastore

I'm trying to get a real mp4 file from the capture of MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE
.
The generated file is not a real MP4 because an iPhone can't read this file. The android produce a 3gpp but with mp4 extension.

I try with an web converter to produce an mp4 from this fake mp4 file and the result works in an Iphone !

Please, how can I do to get a real MP4 ?

My code :

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
                                    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
                                    getContentResolver().delete(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,null);
                                    Uri outputFileUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                                    Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                                    captureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                                    captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
                                    activityResultLauncher.launch(captureIntent);
                                    Log.i("IFFFFF","");

                                } else {
                                    Log.i("ELOOSSEEEE","");
                                    Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "video.mp4");
                                    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                                    captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
                                    activityResultLauncher.launch(captureIntent);
                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to get a real mp4 file from the capture of MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE

There are dozens, if not hundreds, of different apps that will respond to your `Intent`. This includes both pre-installed camera apps from phone manufacturers and user-installed camera apps from places like the Play store. How these apps handle your request is up to their developers. `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`, like `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, is for cases where you do not care about the details of the capture operation.

Since in your case you care about those details, you need to capture the video yourself, whether using `MediaRecorder` directly or using [third-party libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/141?sort=created).